# Can I transfer my save from God Eater Burst (PSP) to God Eater Resurrection or 2 (PS4)?

Tags: god-eater-2, god-eater-burst, god-eater-resurrection

I loved God Eater Burst when it came out years ago. Sadly, I lost the UMD, but still have my savefiles.

Recently, God Eater 2: Rage Burst came out, packed with God Eater 1 remastered as God Eater Resurrection.

Is it possible to import my savefiles to one of these two games?

I m mainly interested to get back my save file from God Eater 1 (Burst => Resurrection) as I spent a *lot* of time on it, and would probably not spend that time again. But would have liked to be able to quickly replay the story to be up to speed before playing God Eater 2.

**tl;dr**: Can I play my God Eater Burst (PSP) savefile on the PS4 remake? Or can I import it in God Eater 2 to get a bonus at start?

Comment: I'm assuming that you cannot transfer a save between God Eater Burst and God Eater 2: Rage Burst, as they are two different games. I'm not sure about Burst to Resurrection, though. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to transferring between God Eater 1 and God Eater 2: Rage Burst, *no*, you cannot do this, as they are two different games.

See [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/438490/discussions/0/360672047209566895/):

> GE:R and GE2 are completely standalone (you're not the same character) so there's no save transfer at all.

---

As for transferring a savefile from your PSP to your PS4, I do not think this is possible. There *is* a transfer/import feature in God Eater Resurrection, but from [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/171961-god-eater-resurrection/73947811), it looks like this is for other savefiles from the same game, which allow you to carry over your character and equipment but restart the story.

> It's for importing your current GER save into a new game so you can redo your character and story while keeping all your progress

---

Note: In case you see [this page on data importation](http://godeater.wikia.com/wiki/Data_Importation), it looks like this is for the **Japanese version only.**

Comment: Sad, I was hoping for a way to at least not start from scratch. Thanks.